# Laravel 5 - multiple use of template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel 5 I am creating a little workaround for a template.

In this template, there are widgets and I want to make a template of this widget and then yield content and title to it.

I have tried something like this:

```
@section('widget-title', 'sdf')
@include('admin.core.widget')
@section('widget-title', 'sdfff')
@include('admin.core.widget')
```

But it did not help.

Comment: "*But it did not help*" Doesn't tell us much... Are you getting an error? What's not working? You have to be more descriptive; provide error messages, expected outcome, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a second argument to `@include()`, which contains any data you want to be sent to the view, as stated in the [blade documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates).

```
@include('admin.core.widget', ['widget-title' => 'sdf'])
@include('admin.core.widget', ['widget-title' => 'sdfff'])
```

You can then access the data in the view using `$widget-title`.

You can also pass more than one variable to the view, like this:

```
@include('admin.core.widget', [
    'widget-title' => 'sdf',
    'widget-content' => 'lorem ipsum...'
])
```

If you want to include variables inside your `$widget-content` variable you could use standard inline PHP:

```
<?php $content = 'lorem ipsum ' . $extra-content . ' dolor...'; ?>

@include('admin.core.widget', [
    'widget-title' => 'sdf',
    'widget-content' => $content
])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What's not working about it? Is there an error or what?

Comment: How are you getting the title in your view? It should be `{{ $widget-title }}`

Comment: Oh, my bad, now it works, but there is a problem. For example, what if i need to put a variable to that content?

Comment: What do you mean? You can replace the `'lorem ipsum...'` part with a variable if you want.

Comment: I mean, if i can put to it smt like this 'lorem {{ $ipsum }} dolor sit amet.'?

Comment: This isn't really related to the question, but I have update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **@overwrite** instead of @endsection or @stop.

Assume you have a `widget.blade.php` with your basic layout like:

```
<h2>
    @yield('widget-title')
</h2>
@yield('widget-content')
```

and let's several widgets like `widget-one.blade.php`, `widget-two.blade.php`, ...

```
@extends('widget')

@section('widget-title')
    Some title
@overwrite

@section('widget-content')
    Some content
@overwrite
```

Now you can `@include('widget-one')`.